# Python: mutliple line code string displays a different output

Tags: python

I have an assignment and I don't want to break the 80 character limit according to my assignment. Hence, when I wrote an condition like this:

```
if not (0 < rate_float < 1.0):
    return False, """The interest rate must be between 0.00 to 1.00. 
                     Please try again"""
```

or an exception like this:

```
except ValueError:
    return False, """Error in converting data to the appropriate data type.
                     Please try again"""
```

The results were printed like this:

```
Error in converting data to the appropriate data type.
                             Please try again
```

I am using the print statement to print an error message like this: `print(result[1])`
I would like to print the output like this in one line:

```
Error in converting data to the appropriate data type.Please try again
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use try/ except clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation `+` operator. This construct must be wrapped in `( ... )` to break it cross more than one code line.

```
def return_error():
    return ('Error in converting data to the appropriate data type. ' +
            'Please try again.')
```

Comment: This worked well for me. Since I am returning a tuple, enclosing it in a paranthesis seems ideal. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: True, but I think would have to be within () to break the line even if you're just returning a string. At least for me if I did it outside ```(...)``` it caused a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("""Error in converting data to the appropriate data type."""
                             """Please try again """)
```

Not sure if this will exceed your char limit. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `False` if the **rate_float** is not between 0.00 to 1.00 and `None` if `ValueError` is raised. I have written a small function that return `rate_float` if it is between 0.00 to 1.00 and if it is number(`if it does not raise ValueError`)

```
def check(rate_float):
    try:
        if not (0 < rate_float < 1.0):
            return False

    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return None

    return rate_float


rate_float = 0.5
_check = check(rate_float)

if _check is False:
    print("""The interest rate must be between 0.00 to 1.00. Please try again""")

elif _check is None:
    print("Error in converting data to the appropriate data type. Please try"
          " again")

else:
    # do_something()
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **\** to break strings.

```
print("The interest rate must be between 0.00 to 1.00."\
            "Please try again")
```

output

```
The interest rate must be between 0.00 to 1.00.Please try again
```

Comment: It worked for me. There is another way, updated the answer. Which also works.